# how to create custom UI like evernote help in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to crate a Custom UI similar to evernote help android app. As I understand, to start with I have to first create a custom Textview But i cant create a black filter.

[image: help]

**I want make new help activity(or draw a view) above the original activity like above image.**

My layout has an image and text overlay on it. I know it is a basic question, but I am facing this issue, as I am a beginner to android development. Please do help me to understand how to go with this.

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: i didn't understand your question well.are you trying to make a new help activity above the orginal activity?

Comment: @Mostafa Rostami can you please explain nicely?

Comment: yes i want make new help activity above the orginal activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the help activity transprent first make a transprent theme in the `styles.xml` file in valuse folded using

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>

  </style>
```

then make in the manifest file make this as the theme of your help activty

```
 <activity 
    android:name=".Help"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

now in the help activty will be displayed over your prvious activity.

Comment: yes its correct but i want show the white focused circle in activity can you explain how to make it

Comment: i think you will have to do that in your help activity background image. you will have to add a transparent area in your background image.

check this [Showcase view](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) library.